# Text color is changing in Android Studio but not showing on phone

Tags: android, textcolor

I have browsed through a few places but can't find anything "exact" to solve my issue. I set code in Android Studio and the display showed my top text as orange and the bottom text as blue...which is what I intended. When I tried running it on my phone, the text color did not show as it does in Android Studio. (Just is gray text on my phone)

This is a simple bit of code as I'm currently learning from Udacity and a couple other places. Any ideas why code would show as working on Android Studio but wouldn't work on the phone? (especially when dealing with something as simple as text color?)

The code is as follows:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.saoiray.happybirthday.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="I'm awesome! Birth of a developer (^_^)"
        android:textColor="#FF5722"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Oh yeah, Stephen is awesome!"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/androidparty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/androidparty"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wondering if that's a sincere question or sarcasm. The code I posted above is everything. This is literally one of the first things the class is having us do...our "hello world." If there's more of anything I can share, might need help knowing where it can be found. Still not sure why, of coding is correct, text color isn't implementing. Something is screwy.

Comment: I guess to diagnose the problem, you could try to run it on an emulator or run it on a different phone. Just tested it on both the emulator and the phone, and the colour changes accordingly. edit: oh, try to remove the imageView. I just realised that your imageview is overlapping your text views. Eliminate as many elements as possible to isolate your problem. That is also a part of being a programmer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and i disabled the "High contrast fonts" from the Settings-> Display -> Visibility enhancements , of the phone and now the textColor appears like in Virtual Device